# Remove a portion from URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
http://www.safi.com/front/property/property_detail.php?pid=12?
```

i want to remove  `front/property`.  This should be

```
http://www.safi.com/property_detail.php?pid-12.
```

And i am writing below code :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/propertydetail/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ propertydetail.php?pid=$3
```

Please help me..........

Answer (score 1):

did u studied this..

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Comment: u need to study regular expression for tat dear..
and its depends on http://domain.com/ and query you are passing with.. i cant give you proper "rule" for tat bz so many things u have to think abt it...

Answer (score 1):

did u try ( not tested)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^front/property/(.*) /$1
```